# Parabolas intersecting in integer points

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

Can you construct an example of two different parabolas (with integer coefficients) that intersect at three integer points?

An integer point is a point $(x,y)$ where both $x$ and $y$ are integers.

Comment: Precisely at three, or at least three?

Comment: At least three. I don't care about the fourth point.

Comment: $y=x^2$ and $y=x^2$.

Comment: Edited the question to rule out identical parabolas. Thanks for pointing the bug.

Comment: Well, given any three non-collinear points you can find a parabola that goes through all of them, so it's "just" a matter of calculation.

Comment: That helps, thanks!

Comment: If by parabola you mean real functions of the form $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, with $a\not=0$, then they are uniquely determined by 3 points.

Comment: "straight" parabola is not enough, two (not identical) parabolas with parallel directrix may intersect in at most 2 places, this is because equation $ax^2+bx+c = a'x^2+b'x+c'$ has at most two solutions. A more general conic section $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F = 0$ equation should be used (with appropriate conditions so it will be a parabola).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Example:**

$$\begin{cases}
x^2+4xy+4y^2-4x-5y=0,\\
4x^2+4xy+y^2-4x-5y=0.
\end{cases}$$

Courtesy of [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2B4xy%2B4y%5E2-4x-5y%3D0%2C+4x%5E2%2B4xy%2By%5E2-4x-5y%3D0):

[image: two parabolas]

I hope this helps ;-)